# Installing NodeJS 4.4.7 or later on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, updates

In order to run a Meteor app created with the latest version of Meteor, I need to install Node.js 4.4.7 or greater on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have followed the instructions in the [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04#how-to-install-using-a-ppa) exactly:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
```

However, when I execute the script, after a number of Get and Ign processes which seem to terminate without error, I get one `404 Not Found` error, and then notification about `Error executing command, exiting`:

```
...
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Fetched 190 kB in 2s (74.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I have been able to install NodeJS 4.2.6, using `sudo apt-get install nodejs` but I have been unable to update to a newer version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the following steps solve this issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash
```

Close and reopen terminal session

```
source ~/.profile
nvm ls-remote
nvm install v4.4.7
nvm use v4.4.7
node -v
```

Shows:

```
v4.4.7
```

Source:[Installing using Node Version Manager (NVM)](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/installing-nodejs-ubuntu-16-04/)

Note: `curl <url> | bash` requires trust in the provider of the downloaded script.